# How do I handle Realm Object Server dying after accidentally performing a migration on iOS (Bad changeset error)?

Tags: realm

Made the mistake of performing a destructive migration on a synchronized realm, which I just now learned I shouldn’t have done according to the docs' statement “However, if the migration makes a destructive change, the Realm will stop syncing with ROS, producing a Bad changeset received error”. The server won't restart our Realm Object Server and the logs say `realm-object-server dead but pid file exists`. We cannot even access ROS on web at this point.

Is there a way around this without re-installing our realm instance? Also, if the magnitude of this migration is so severe, is there not a way to give a warning to the developer?

Code Sample:

`let config = Realm.Configuration(
syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: curUser, realmURL: RealmURL.userObjects), migrationBlock: { (migration, schema) in 
    // todo 
})`

Comment: How did you perform a destructive change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a schema change, this results in an operation that is appended to the operation log maintained by a Realm. This first occurs on the client copy of a synchronized Realm and is then synced to Realm Object Server. If the operation is a destructive change, the server should simply reject the operation and return an error. The result is that the server's operation log is not affected but the client is now in a state where it can't continue to sync with the server. In this situation, the solution is to reset the client, which is easiest in development by deleting and reinstalling the app.

Your situation, however, sounds like a different problem. The fact that the server is unresponsive implies something else went wrong. You could try removing and reinstalling the server since this does not delete the data or configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We did end up just restarting ROS. Looks like they are going to look into more https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/223#issuecomment-312807135